Define variable to auto run extension on file load
Is it possible to predefine some type of constant inside my own php extension, so php compiler will recognise it in file and then passes php code to my extension? I want to write some sort of custom encoder for php source code.
Something like this will be written in php file:
<?php
@MagickWord //Passes all code below to my extension
?>
VmpGb2QxUXhWWGxUYTJScVUwWktWRmx0ZUdGaU1WcHhVbXhrYVdKSGREVlVWVkpYWWtkS1NWRnNWbFpXZWtaMldWWmFXbVF5VGtsVWJIQk9ZbGhvUlZkWGNFdFNNV1JZVkd0b2JGSXpRbWhhVjNCQ1RsRTlQUT09 

And the rest of file after @MagickWord will be processed inside specific class\function in my written php extension.
But there also appears new question for me - is it possible to "do some magick with php code" and then pass it directly to php interpreter?

PHP obfuscators exist, and have done for many years, so the answer to whether it's possible is clearly "yes". Describing how they work would be too broad a topic for this site, as discussed in the [help].

@IMSoP I don't talk about the whole process, but maybe anyone can provide any basic extension .c/.h code example which detecting specific words combination/pattern in php code and then trigger function launch...I tried to search in official docs, but didn't found any viable option.

I still think, as written, the question is very broad. One example you might be able to look at is the build-in PHAR extension, because PHAR files contain a combination of PHP and binary content.
